# Python: How to only URL Encode a specific URL Parameter?

Tags: python, urllib, urlencode, urllib3

I have some big URLs that contain a lot of URL parameters.

For my specific case, I need to URL Encode the content of one specific URL Parameter (q) when the content after the "q=" starts with a slash ("/")

**Example URL:**

```
https://www.exmple.com/test?test1=abc&test2=abc&test3=abc&q=/"TEST"/"TEST"
```

How can I only URL encode that last part of the URL which is within the "q" parameter?

The output of this example should be:

```
https://www.exmple.com/test?test1=abc&test2=abc&test3=abc&q=%2F%22TEST%22%2F%22TEST%22%20
```

I already tried some different things with urllib.parse but it doesnt work the way I want it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please edit the code of your honest attempt to solve this into your question as a [mre], including a few examples of input and the output produced alongside what you want to produce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split the string on the `&q=/` part and only encode the last string

```py
from urllib import parse

url = 'https://www.exmple.com/test?test1=abc&test2=abc&test3=abc&q=/"TEST"/"TEST"'
encoded = parse.quote_plus(url.split("&q=/")[1])
encoded_url = f"{url.split('&q=/')[0]}&q=/{encoded}"
print(encoded_url)
```

**output**

```
https://www.exmple.com/test?test1=abc&test2=abc&test3=abc&q=%2F%22TEST%22%2F%22TEST%22
```

Note that there's a difference between this and the requested output, but you have an url encoded space (`%20`) at the end

---

**EDIT**

Comment shows a different need for the encoding, so the code needs to change a bit. The code below only encodes the part after `&q=`. Basically, first split the url and the parameters, then iterate through the parameters to find the `q=` parameter, and encode that part. Do some f-string and join magic and you get an url that has the `q` parameter encoded. Note that this might have issues if an `&` is present in the part that needs to be encoded.

```py
url = 'https://www.exmple.com/test?test1=abc&test2=abc&test3=abc&q=/"TEST"/"TEST"&utm_source=test1&cpc=123&gclid=abc123'
# the first parameter is always delimited by a ?
baseurl, parameters = url.split("?")
newparameters = []
for parameter in parameters.split("&"):
    # check if the parameter is the part that needs to be encoded
    if parameter.startswith("q="):
        # encode the parameter
        newparameters.append(f"q={parse.quote_plus(parameter[2:])}")
    else:
        # otherwise add the parameter unencoded
        newparameters.append(parameter)
# string magic to create the encoded url
encoded_url = f"{baseurl}?{'&'.join(newparameters)}"
print(encoded_url)
```

**output**

```
https://www.exmple.com/test?test1=abc&test2=abc&test3=abc&q=%2F%22TEST%22%2F%22TEST%22&utm_source=test1&cpc=123&gclid=abc123
```

---

**EDIT 2**

Trying to solve the edge case where there's a `&` character in the string to be encoded, as this messes up the `string.split("&")`.
I tried using `urllib.parse.parse_qs()` but this has the same issue with the `&` character. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs) for reference.

This question is a nice example of how edge cases can mess up simple logic and make it overly complicated.

The [RFC3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.4) also didn't specify any limitations on the name of the query string, otherwise that could've been used to narrow down possible errors even more.

**updated code**

```py
from urllib import parse


url = 'https://www.exmple.com/test?test1=abc&test2=abc&test3=abc&q=/"TEST"/&"TE&eeST"&utm_source=test1&cpc=123&gclid=abc123'
# the first parameter is always delimited by a ?
baseurl, parameters = url.split("?")

# addition to handle & in the querystring.
# it reduces errors, but it can still mess up if there's a = in the part to be encoded.
split_parameters = []
for index, parameter in enumerate(parameters.split("&")):
    if "=" not in parameter:
        # add this part to the previous entry in split_parameters
        split_parameters[-1] += f"&{parameter}"
    else:
        split_parameters.append(parameter)


newparameters = []
for parameter in split_parameters:
    # check if the parameter is the part that needs to be encoded
    if parameter.startswith("q="):
        # encode the parameter
        newparameters.append(f"q={parse.quote_plus(parameter[2:])}")
    else:
        # otherwise add the parameter unencoded
        newparameters.append(parameter)
# string magic to create the encoded url
encoded_url = f"{baseurl}?{'&'.join(newparameters)}"
print(encoded_url)
```

**output**

```
https://www.exmple.com/test?test1=abc&test2=abc&test3=abc&q=%2F%22TEST%22%2F%26%22TE%26eeST%22&utm_source=test1&cpc=123&gclid=abc123
```

Comment: Thanks for your great help. I have one more problem with the code. Sometimes, after the the q parameter there are more parameters coming. With your code, also the other parameters get URL encoded which I don't want. How can I ensure that only the content of the q parameter gets encoded, no matter where in the URL it is located? I think I have to parse the URL and not just split it at some point but I can't figure out how to exactly do this.

Example URL:
https://www.exmple.com/test?test1=abc&test2=abc&test3=abc&q=/"TEST"/"TEST"&utm_source=test1&cpc=123&gclid=abc123

Comment: see my edit. This requires a bit more logic, and will have an issue if a `&` character is present in the part to be encoded

Comment: @EdoAkse I almost added an answer identical to yours (except I called them "args" and you called them "parameters").  Well done!

Comment: @RufusVS I stole the part `baseurl, parameters = url.split("?")` from you. I keep forgetting that you can do that weird magic in python. @SERPY, I edited the code to reduce the number of issues when the part to be encoded contains a `&` character.

Answer (score 1):

@EdoAkse has a good answer, and should get the credit for the answer.

But the purist in me would do the same thing slightly differently, because

(1) I don't like doing the same function on the same data twice (for efficiency), and

(2) I like the logical symmetry of using the join function to reverse a split.

My code would look more like this:

```
from urllib import parse

url = 'https://www.exmple.com/test?test1=abc&test2=abc&test3=abc&q=/"TEST"/"TEST"'
splitter = "&q=/"   
unencoded,encoded = url.split(splitter)
encoded_url = splitter.join(unencoded,parse.quote_plus(encoded))
print(encoded_url)
```

Edit:  I couldn't resist posting my edited answer based on the commentary.  You can see the virtual identical code developed independently.  This must be the right approach then, I guess.

```
from urllib import parse
url = 'https://www.exmple.com/test?test1=abc&test2=abc&test3=abc&q=/"TEST"/"TEST"'
base_url,arglist = url.split("?",1)
args = arglist.split("&")
new_args = []
for arg in args:
    if arg.lower().startswith("q="):
        new_args.append(arg[:2]+parse.quote_plus(arg[2:]))
    else:
        new_args.append(arg)
encoded_url = "?".join([base_url,"&".join(new_args)])
print(encoded_url)
```